# Interested in having Stack Exchange provide free food and stuff for your group?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

The [Stack Exchange Ambassadors](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1962/are-you-an-english-student-or-teacher-do-you-want-some-free-food) program provides free food and Stack Exchange swag to student and teacher groups who agree to promote relevant Stack Exchange sites. We have an offer on the table to expand the program to Judaism.SE.

The particulars are subject to negotiation, but basically, we'd ask you to make Judaism.SE part of your programming, and you'd get food and stuff. So, if you're involved in a Jewish student group (high school or college), a Jewish faculty group, or perhaps a Jewish youth or outreach group, and you're interested in this idea, please get in touch by responding here or by emailing me at info@yodeya.com .

---

UPDATE: As noted below, our first ambassador event has been scheduled. If you are interested in holding one in your neck of the woods, please do get in touch! There is still funding available in the budget Stack Exchange has allocated for Judaism.SE promotional activities.

Comment: Kosher food, I hope...

Comment: @yydl - Lol. FYI, I'm doing one of these for English.SE in my English class, I'll see how it goes.

Comment: "This week's kiddush is sponsored by R' Yoel Spolsky in honor go Judaism.StackExchange." - Local Gabbai

Comment: @yydl, Of course. I'm pretty sure that the volunteer ambassador would be purchasing the food and getting reimbursed.

Comment: moshe that bis hilarious

Comment: can they come to YU?

Comment: @ArielK, That would be my first guess of a school where this could work out. Are you involved in any groups there that could be amenable?

Comment: Related: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/468/conversation/yu-event-planning

Answer (score 10):

[Ariel K](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/users/369/ariel-k) is arranging a lunchtime event at [Yeshiva University](http://yu.edu) to introduce students there to Judaism.SE. It's jointly sponsored by Stack Exchange, the Student Organization of Yeshiva, and the YU Computer Science Club. It will be on Wednesday, February 29, at 12:05 pm, in Belfer 218.

Thanks very much for arranging this, Ariel K!

Comment: Here's the Facebook event: https://www.facebook.com/events/305896229473477/

Comment: It seems this event will be overlapping with Parshat HaShavua Chat. Maybe you could integrate this fact into the program (ie showing the chat live or something). Just a thought.

Comment: @DoubleAA, we discussed that idea in our [planning session](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/468/conversation/yu-event-planning). I think the conclusion was that the event should focus on the core site functionality - Q&A.

Comment: @ArielK, What masechta/perek/sugya is YU learning these days? It might be worthwhile to propose it as a weekly topic challenge and ask msh210 designate it as such next week.

Comment: If you say so, but I don't see the word 'shavua' in that chat transcript.

Comment: IIRC I think they are doing Yevamot. (Kind of an odd topic to pick IMO)

Comment: @DoubleAA My mistake. That was in an off-line conversation.

Comment: @IsaacMoses, YU is doing Yevamot. I agree with doubleAA that its probably not the best choice for a weekly topic.

Comment: @ArielK Why not? If we have a bunch of people on the site who are learning it, it could be fodder for a bunch of worthwhile questions. Not every topic has to appeal to everyone.

Comment: event details can also be found on https://rail.adm.yu.edu:8443/wv3/wv3_servlet/urd/run/wv_event.Detail?id=2521471

Comment: Had a great time at the judaism.se event, thanks to Ariel and co.http://i.stack.imgur.com/sFq2n.jpg

Comment: @Moshe, thanks for the pic! I'd be very interested to hear more about how it went from you, Ariel, or anyone else who was there.

Comment: Any idea if this event generated any new users that you seasoned users have noticed?

Comment: @KateyHW, yes, there were a bunch who stopped in and at least a couple who stuck around.

Comment: Awesome, good to know!