# Weekly topic challenge 5772-20 (week of T'tzave 5772): Yevamot

Tags: discussion, status-completed, weekly-topic-challenge

**This week's topic challenge is *Yevamot*. You're encouraged to think of and [post good questions](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) on this topic.**

#### Topic Proposal

> I propose **"Yevamot"** as a challenge topic.
>
> Such a challenge could spark questions related to the tractate in [Nashim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nashim) by that name as well as questions related to [Yibbum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yibbum) in general. The [yibum-chalitza-levirate](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yibum-chalitza-levirate) tag currently contains three questions.
>
> There are many interesting concepts connected to Yibbum, and anyone who learns Yevamot tends to have many questions, as its complicated family configuration cases tend to be difficult to keep track of. In addition, [Yeshiva University](http://yu.edu) is [learning](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/522/interested-in-having-stack-exchange-provide-free-food-and-stuff-for-your-group#comment1833_823) Yevamot this year, so this challenge could be particularly effective at inspiring them to pose their questions here. This could potentially work out well if this challenge is activated on Wednesday, February 29, 2012, when there is going to be a Judaism.SE [event](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/823/2) at YU.

Note that, in line with existing tags on other *masechtot*, questions about *masechet Yevamot* can be tagged [masechet-yevamot](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/masechet-yevamot) (unused as of this writing).

#### What is it?

There's a single topic that people think about during the week and come up with good questions on. The topic is set each Wednesday or so.

#### What do I win?

An Internet with more good questions and answers on an interesting topic.

#### How do we decide on *next* week's topic?

See [the call for topic proposals](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/441).

Comment: Wouldn't you want the challenge to be finishing at that time so the students can see the results?

Comment: @DoubleAA I want their participation more than I want their admiration.

Answer (score 1):

The only question asked on this topic during its week was ["So should be done to the man"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15057), which is thus the winner of this week's challenge by default. Congratulations to its author, Double AA!